# What does "Aman deAmar" mean?

Tags: words, talmud-gemara

I go to a [Gemara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemara) shiur, and the rabbi always says "the first aman deamar", "the second aman deamar"... What does it mean exactly? What is the meaning of the different words?

Comment: JOJO, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: the "man de'amar" is "the one who says" and it is used to introduce a particular opinion (as in "this explanation works according to the one who says X but..." or "the first man de'amar holds that").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The words you're actually hearing are "man de'amar", or מאן דאמר in Aramaic.

"Man" here actually has the same meaning in Aramaic as in English - man. "D'amar" is like the Hebrew שאמר. Translated, it means "who says".

The whole phrase together means "the [first/second] one who says".

It's often used as a noun when talking about different opinions - "this *man d'amar* says *x*, while the other *man d'amar* says *y*". Or: "according to the first *man d'amar*...".

---

While not the case you're talking about, *aman d'amar* (אמאן דאמר) is also an Aramaic phrase. The initial א means "on", so it means "on the one who says". Maybe i'm not listening to the right shiruim, but i haven't heard this used so much in English.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/5449

Comment: "The whole phrase together means 'the [first/second] one who says'." I don't think there's usually a "first/second" implied. It's just "the one who says [such-and-such]".

Comment: "first/second" is only because the OP talks about "first man d'amar".

Comment: Oh, I see. But that's AFAIK only in its colloquial use as a noun, not in its original use meaning "the one who says".